# invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' при вызове метода

Tags: c++, классы

понимаю, что просходит конфликт типов, но не могу исправить. 
рассчёт массива и вызов метода

```
int scores2[5];
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << "Введите число" << i + 1 << ":";
    cin >> scores2[i];
    sum += scores2[i];
}

objStudents.SetScores(scores2[5]);
```

отрывок из класса, а именно сам метод и объявление переменных в private.

```
void SetScores(int Scores1[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Scores[i] = Scores1[i];
    }
}

private:
   int Scores[5];
```

как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

`SetScores` ожидает получить массив, а Вы передаете ей `int` (ведь `scores2[5]` - это `int`, который находится за пределами массива). Передавайте так: `objStudents.SetScores(scores2);`.